# Adding edge attributes in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to add edge labels to my edges in networkx. I will use `nx.write_dot()` to convert it into a dot file. How can I do this? When I do this: `G.add_edge("ATC", "TCG", label = "ATCG")`, `nx.write_dot()` throws an error. I like networkx, but if it can't label edges then I think I'll have to use another library.

Specifically, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/networkx/drawing/nx_agraph.py", line 180, in write_dot
    A.clear()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 907, in clear
    self.edge_attr.clear()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/collections/abc.py", line 553, in clear
    self.popitem()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/collections/abc.py", line 542, in popitem
    key = next(iter(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 1692, in __iter__
    for (k,v) in self.iteritems():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 1700, in iteritems
    yield (gv.agattrname(ah).decode(self.encoding),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: What error do you get? I have used networkx with edge attributes fine, but with graphml, not dot (and not label)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work something like this:

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.Graph()

In [3]: G.add_edge(1,2,label='one-two')

In [4]: import sys

In [5]: nx.write_dot(G,sys.stdout)
strict graph  {
    1 -- 2   [label="one-two"];
}
```

Comment: I get the output, but I added the error message to my post

Comment: I'm also using python3.3, if that's a problem.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't notice that.  You'll need either PyGraphviz or Pydot in addition to NetworkX.  PyGraphviz definitely does not work with Python 3 but Pydot might - see https://code.google.com/p/pydot/

Comment: How does networkx interface with PyGraphviz and Pydot? Can the networkx be treated as a PyGraphviz or Pydot graph?

Comment: The networkx structure is converted to a pydot or pygraphviz structure before writing the file/data. See networkx.to_pydot() or networkx.to_agraph() respectively.